# Saving last NSManagedObject before exit and retrieval - core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I use `nsfetchedresultscontroller` to maintain entity "Product". 
But i set a predicate `"forUser==%@", currentUser"`, User is another entity.

Though i can load in the currentUser at runtime, but I wanted to save the "CurrentUser" somewhere in nsuserdefaults, in SQL i'd save the primaryKey of that User there,
On appDidFinishLaunching i could grab that and get the entity.

Im not sure what exactly i should save when it comes to an Entity in the NSUserDefaults.

I don't want to add an extra attribute of

> "last accessed"

to the user, cuz at a time, there is only One current user, and it makes sense to just same some kinda ID. I can save the lastName or firstName, but was thinking about a better way to do it, like some kinda integerID.

Saving `NSManagedObjectID URI` was also an option, but that would change incase of any migration or core data graph changes, and break the app on update.

please help me understand this in core data.

Comment: So the User entity has a unique attribute? say id? then you can save that id in NSUSerDefaults.

Comment: I didn't add any, thinking that its all taken care of by Coredata model. Potentially theres no need for an Integer primaryKey cuz core data makes on for is, but doesn't make it available? User has no ID attribute as of now.. Im thinking of another way?.. besides adding a new ID like attribute?

Comment: You have to add an id given the usecase you mentioned. You wanted to store it in NsUserDefaults right

Comment: Your right @mbh That seems the only way out. I decided to use UUIDs, incase the users are unique and shared across iCloud, I'll accept your answer if you'd written it as an answer..

Comment: Lol true. I did post it as an answer now. But too late I guess!

Comment: sorry man, couldn't give both correct answers :)

Comment: Why did you downvote! After spending several minutes helping you out....

Comment: no i didn't down vote at all, infact i don't have enough reputation to either down vote or up vote.. thats weird..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to add an id given the usecase you mentioned. You wanted to store it in NsUserDefaults right?

Comment: Yep :| a string perhaps, What would you feel about a UUID? using that as a unique identifier for the User.

Comment: this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349606/custom-uid-data-type-for-coredata

Answer (score 0):

You've answered your own question. You're saying you want a way to uniquely identify users.

If Users don't have a uniquely identifying attribute, then you only have the `NSManagedObjectID URI`. But that can change during migrations.

So you need to add an attribute that uniquely identifies users, or at least uniquely identifies the last user.

Comment: Yea, that would be sad that i'd have to add a UID, thanks for making it clear man.. If you'd allow me to extend the question a bit, you think if i'd use a UUID? 'NSString *uuid = nil;
CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
if (theUUID) {
  uuid = NSMakeCollectable(CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, theUUID));
  [uuid autorelease];
  CFRelease(theUUID);
}' if I decided to use iCloud?

Comment: Just use the NSManagedObjectID, no need to create another UUID. If you ever need to migrate, just store the old object ID, then migrate, then obtain the new object ID. Then store that one in the user defaults. That's one of the purposes of the object ID.